# google colab cannot find a file in a local directory

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am new to `google colab`, and trying to read a file in a local directory in the computer not to read from the google drive. The file path is correct, but the colab cannot find it. The `os.path.exists()` gives `False`.

What is the problem? Can google colab access the local file directly other than by uploading to google drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colab runs Python code within a cloud virtual machine that has no access to your local filesystem. For information on how to move files from various sources into the colab VM, see https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb